# Can't install graphviz by using "conda install python-graphviz" or "conda install graphviz"

Tags: python, graphviz

I tried install `graphviz` package using `pip install graphviz`, and I succesfully import it in jupyter notebook with python3, but failed to run the code below:

```
s = Source.from_file("tree_test.dot")
s.view()
```

The `tree_test.dot` file is under the current working directory. The error message is:

```
ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Kdot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'tree_test.dot'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

I was advised to uninstall `graphviz` first using `pip uninstall graphviz` and then tried `conda install graphviz` and `conda install python-graphviz`, respectively. But both of them failed to install `graphviz` and here is the error message :

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: | 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
.....
#(spend long time examining conflict and shows what those conflicts are but still failed to install graphviz)#
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Anaconda's package documentation](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/graphviz), You need to type:

```
conda install -c anaconda graphviz
```

Comment: Same problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Update your Anaconda first by using

```
conda update anaconda
```

then follow with

```
conda install -c anaconda graphviz
```

because installing using the 2nd line itself doesn't help if your Anaconda isn't updated. The error message comes from Anaconda incompatibility with the graphviz version.